# Azure Site to Site only with Pre-Shared key?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn

I want to create Site to Site VPN in Azure.
Azure VNG will connect to On-premises network throught LNG. But this scenario request only Pre-Shared key. Why? Certificates are more secure than Pre-Shared key. If router doesn´t using protokol with Pre-Shared key than what can I do? Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Azure is limited to using pre-shared keys (PSK) for authentication.